# Как перезапустить adsl-модем?

Tags: php

Как перезапустить (перезагрузить) adsl-модем с помощью php?

Comment: Вопрос из серии "Как с помощью электролобзика завести дизельный генератор теплохода"

Comment: @Johny, вы зря иронизируете. Это вполне можно реализовать.

Comment: И в какую сторону копать? Создавать искать бинарник, или еще видел кто-то делал: заходил в настройки модема по адресу 192,168,1,1 и там брал ссылку для ребута...

Comment: В свое время делал bat'ник, который по telnet'у отсылал запрос ребута.

Посмотрите первый пример http://php.net/manual/ru/sockets.examples.php
____
Можно попробовать перезапустить как вы говорите из ссылки, путем добавления логина/пароля
http://user:password@192.168.1.1/reboot.cgi
Ссылку и данные соответственно подменить. Однако это для вариантов модемов с http-авторизацией.